# Convert string into JSON or other data structure in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, ecmascript-6

The data comes as props from the parent component:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <Table data={this.state.apiResponse} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and the Table component is below. If the data is sent like this is is sent to render as a whole, it is shown on the screen. This is how `this.props.data` [looks like](https://pastebin.com/0641h1BH).

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>{data}</tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

The problem appears when I want to modify that data. For example, if in `render()` is added:

`console.log(typeof data)` -> returns `string`

So I tried to convert it to JSON:

`const convertedData = JSON.parse(data);` -> returns error message:

**Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.**

Is it something wrong with the format of `this.props.data`? How can I convert it from string to other data structure? (because I need to performs `map` and `reduce` on it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all your Table component requires a return statement. However regarding the original question, I'm suspecting your api is return something different from your expected response. I created a .json file with your expected data, imported data in App, and rendered Table inside app.

Whats the result when you console log data in Table component.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import apiData from './api'
import Table from "./Table";

function App() {
     return (
        <div className="App">
             <header className="App-header">
                   <Table data={apiData} />
             </header>
        </div>
     );
}
export default App;
```

Table.js

```
import React, {PureComponent} from "react";

export default class Table extends PureComponent{

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                         <tr>{data[0].game_id} {typeof data}</tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```